# Transformation rule for a wedge product

Tags: exterior-algebra

Suppose two sets of covectors on a vector space $V, \beta^1,...\beta^k $ and $\gamma^1,...,\gamma^k,$ are related by

$$\beta^i=\sum_{j=1}^k a^i_j \gamma ^j$$

where $i=1,...,k$, for a $k\times k$ matrix $[a^i_j]$.

I want to show

$$\beta^1 \wedge...\wedge\beta^k=(det A) \gamma^1 \wedge...\wedge\gamma^k$$

but my efforts fail. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\beta^i=\sum_{j=1}^k a^i_j \gamma ^j$ then consider,
\begin{align} \beta^1 \wedge  \cdots \wedge  \beta^k &= \biggl[ \sum_{j_1=1}^k a^1_{j_1} \biggr] \gamma ^{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \biggl[\sum_{j_k=1}^k a^k_{j_k} \gamma ^{j_k} \biggr]\\
&=  \sum_{j_1=1}^k \sum_{j_k=1}^k a^1_{j_1}   \cdots a^k_{j_k} \gamma ^{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge   \gamma ^{j_k} \\
&=  \sum_{j_1=1}^k \sum_{j_k=1}^k a^1_{j_1}   \cdots a^k_{j_k} \epsilon^{j_1 \cdots j_k}\gamma ^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge   \gamma ^k \\
&=  det[A] \gamma^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \gamma^k. 
\end{align}
Here I use the anti-symmetric symbol to define the determinant (as is my custom).

Comment: Thank you James, this is excellent!

Comment: @Jellyfish you might look at page 183 of http://www.supermath.info/math332.pdf (these notes are not optimal, but that example is what you want to see)

Comment: :( I wish I am in your class...

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say, those notes are amazing! Thanks James. You definitely should get it published! It will help so many students!! They are detailed and comprehensable, I feel your notes talk to me!

Comment: @Jellyfish I'll send you my more recent notes once I've fixed them... I haven't posted them in a very accessible way due to the lack of quality control... many errors. Thanks for your comment.